# Dynamically Setting ScrollViewer Height

Tags: c#, xaml, grid-layout, winui-3, uwp-scrollviewer

I'm currently working on a WinUI 3 app, and I'm trying to have a `StackPanel` above and below a `ScrollViewer` which will always be visible (not depending on the size of the screen or the elements in the `ScrollViewer`):

```xml
<Grid Margin="30,30,30,30">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Name="projectNumber" Text="Project Number" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Name="taskName" Text="Task" Width="750" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Name="dueDate" Text="Due Date" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Name="assignedBy"  Text="Assigned By" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Line Name="dividerLine" Stroke="DimGray" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1130" Y2="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="2">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView Name="tasksPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ListView Name="completeTasksPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

However, the `ScrollViewer` element won't have its height set according to the screen, instead, it will take up as much space as the elements inside. I also tried setting the `Grid.RowDefinitions` with a set height instead of `Auto`, but it made no difference:

```xml
<RowDefinition Height="50"/>
<RowDefinition Height="3"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="50"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `StackPanel` in the `ScrollViewer` with another `Panel` that doesn't measure its child elements with infinite vertical space, such as for example a `Grid`:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="tasksPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="completeTasksPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The other option is to specify a fixed height for the `StackPanel`.

`ScrollViewers` and `StackPanels` don't work very well together because of the (infinite measurement) characteristics of the latter.

Comment: This worked great! And thanks for the explanation, I had another `StackPanel` that was also part of the problem.